# Parametrizing the surface $z=7-x^2-4y^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, conic-sections, 3d, parametrization

I am willing to parameterize the surface formed by paraboloid $z=7-x^2-4y^2$ bounded below by the plane $z=3$. i know its simple that parameterize is $x=u$, $y=v$ and $z=7-u^2-4v^2$
But i am unable to decide range of values of $u$ and $v$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersection of the plane $z=3\;$ and the parabolic surface is the ellipse
$$\frac{x^2}{4}+{y^2}=1$$ which can be parameterized by generalized polar coordinates $(r,\varphi)$ as
$$\begin{aligned}x=&\; 2r\cos\varphi
\\y=&\; r\sin\varphi
\\z=&\; 7-4r^2\end{aligned}$$
Here $\varphi\in[0,2\pi),\;r\in[0,1].$